# SQL Server 2016 Suspend using SQL Server Import and Export Wizard

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

This problem has appeared out of the wild and will not go away.
We are doing a load from a local server to a live external SQL server, both 2016. It is a single table with about 1.5mil rows.

Using the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard, it will randomly hit a `ASYNC_NETWORK_IO` wait and suspend. I've tried increasing packet size, setting MAX DOPs to specific values, disabling AV, using the .NET provider, nothing has worked.

I just don't know what do, our network connection isn't bad, it's on average 1.5 to 4 MBs/sec. But why would even a slow connection cause SQL to bail on a query randomly - shouldn't it be able to serve clients on slower connections? Memory usage is low, about 1/4th max. CPU is 10%...

Any way I could figure out why this is occurring and how to resolve it?

`sp_who2` and `sp_lock`:
[image: sp_who2 and sp_lock]

Server settings:
[image]

[image]

On the local side, the local database server hit's the same suspend condition, but on the SELECT query side.

Comment: I've also tried restarting the server, then doing the load immediately, same issue.

Comment: SQL Server historically been somewhat deficient in dealing with network interruptions (even minor ones). I suggest you export your table to a file, copy the file over to the remote server  and import it locally.